# bash script sftp exit terminate script

Tags: bash, sftp

Im new in bash scripting and Ive met a problem
here is the example of my script

```
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H")

echo -e "\nSFTP connection"
sftp username@ip <<EOT
lcd local_folder/
cd remote_folder/
mget *.txt
exit
EOT

##here it stops  

echo -e "\nNew folder"

cat email_list | while read line
do
    mail -s "topic" $line < text.txt
done

echo -e "\nSent"

}
```

When im closing the connection with ftp the script stops and doesnt return the second part of the script:(

Please give me suggestions about what im doing wrong

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the whole script.

Comment: Is `EOT` at the left margin of the script? It won't be recognized if it's indented.

Comment: You can use `<<-EOT`, which allows `EOT` to be indented, but _only_ with TAB characters, not spaces.

Comment: what is the "}" at end ? is this a bash script ?

Comment: Got it working! Thank you Barmar for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Is EOT at the left margin of the script? It won't be recognized if it's indented. –  Barmar

You can use <<-EOT, which allows EOT to be indented, but only with TAB characters, not spaces. –  Barmar